# Zend_Form as database filter

Tags: zend-framework, filtering

In mij admin i have a list of posts but this list is really really big. I want to make a send form that i can use to active an database filter (so the form gets translated to where / and / or filters). Is there some good example code that i could read or maybe a tutorial ?. Any advise ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A [nice & short previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987532/where-does-zend-form-fit-in-the-model-view-controller-paradigma/4018185#4018185) on that.
- The [reference Matthew Weier O'Phinney's page](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/200-Using-Zend_Form-in-Your-Models.html) on Zend_Form used in the Model layer
- And [just another one](http://www.whitewashing.de/blog/109) if you want

Search on goole with 'Zend_Form' and 'Model Layer' will certainly gives you some others.